# Using another query inside IFNULL() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for some help with a SQL query. I have a table `payment_plan` with columns `payment_method`, `validto`, and `validfrom`. `payment_method` can be something like 'CC' or 'CASH'; however it can also be '*' for all types.

I am trying to select the plans that are currently active and only match a specific payment method.

However, if no records exist for that `payment_method`, it will check for a record with '*' as the `payment_method`. I tried using an IFNULL statement to only check if `payment_method` is equal to '*' if there are no records with a `payment_method` equal to 'CC', but I am getting an error doing that.

So does anybody know of a better way of doing this. Here is a SQLFiddle with what I have tried:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/294845/3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would use `ifnull()`. Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT payment_method
FROM payment_plan 
WHERE ptid = 100 AND
      validfrom <= CURDATE() AND
      validto > CURDATE() AND
      payment_method IN ('CC', '*') ;
```

If you want only one row returned, with priority for the non-`'*'` value, then add:

```
ORDER BY (payment_method <> '*') desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It was just that second part of giving payment_methods that were not '*' priority that was giving me trouble but this works perfectly. Thank you!